# Removing upper and lower quintiles from data in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I'm trying to remove the upper and lower quintiles from a data set. I can see there is a `quartile` function but not one for quintiles.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Are you after `quantile`?

Comment: No, I want to remove the upper and lower quintiles.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- df[quantile(df$x, probs = c(.2)) < x & x < quantile(x, probs = c(.8)),]
```